# Get user login records by login day of week

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with user id and login time:

```
CREATE TABLE session(user_id int, login_time int)

INSERT INTO session
SELECT 99, 1459468305 UNION ALL
SELECT 101, 1459467646 UNION ALL
SELECT 111, 1459448891 UNION ALL
SELECT 112, 145958778
```

Would like to categories  users based on login time, as per day_of_week or week_end for which they login.

**EDIT**

My expectation is to get count distribution of users' login by weekdays, like so:

```
+----------+-----------+
| weekends | week-days |
+----------+-----------+
|        2 |         3 |
+----------+-----------+
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=db61da401a3a834cd072a46c97647066)

Comment: Please show us the result that you would expect for this sample data.

Comment: Question edited to show what's expected from as the output.

Comment: @arilwan . . . You have four rows but your results add to 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select count(*) filter (where extract(dow from '1970-01-01'::timestamp + login_time * interval '1 second') in (0, 6)) as weekends,
       count(*) filter (where extract(dow from '1970-01-01'::timestamp + login_time * interval '1 second') not in (0, 6)) as weekdays
from sessions;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9ac12534fa6c48078abb725ea8f58020) is a db<>fiddle.